# Inserting HTML tags using PHP

Tags: php, html

I want to be able to dynamically insert an HTML tag, by first copying it to a textarea and then submitting it.

This is my first attempt.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Tag Parser</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="tagInput" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
Input Tags:<br>
<textarea name="tag" id="tag">

</textarea>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php 
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = str_replace('"', "'", $value);
    echo "field " . $key . " " .  "value " . htmlentities($value) . "<br>";
    echo "$value";
}

?>

</body>

</html>
```

When I output the tag with htmlentities(), I see it is formated properly and just like I'd like it to show, but rendered. But then, the second echo is adding the tag, but broken.

This was my input:

```
<IFRAME SRC="http://ad.doubleclick.net/adi/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?" WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 MARGINWIDTH=0 MARGINHEIGHT=0 HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 FRAMEBORDER=0 SCROLLING=no BORDERCOLOR='#000000'> <SCRIPT language='JavaScript1.1' SRC="http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?"> </SCRIPT> <NOSCRIPT> <A HREF="http://ad.doubleclick.net/jump/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie4;abr=!ie5;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?"> <IMG SRC="http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie4;abr=!ie5;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?" BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 ALT="Advertisement"></A> </NOSCRIPT> </IFRAME>
```

This is what's being generated in the site:

```
<iframe src="" width="300" height="250" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" bordercolor="#000000"> &lt;SCRIPT language='JavaScript1.1' SRC='http://ad.doubleclick.net/adj/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?'&gt; &lt;/SCRIPT&gt; &lt;NOSCRIPT&gt; &lt;A HREF='http://ad.doubleclick.net/jump/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie4;abr=!ie5;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?'&gt; &lt;IMG SRC='http://ad.doubleclick.net/ad/N7480.147698OMGBLOG1/B8174590.109702939;abr=!ie4;abr=!ie5;sz=300x250;ord=[timestamp]?' BORDER=0 WIDTH=300 HEIGHT=250 ALT='Advertisement'&gt;&lt;/A&gt; &lt;/NOSCRIPT&gt; </iframe>
```

The src= is empty and the tag is clearly broken (not rendering anything)

Comment: Why don't you just add the link itself in the textbox and use the `iframe + src=""` in the foreach loop?

Comment: @JimSundqvist Thanks for your reply! I wanted to preserve the original tag structure since I am doing this to test the tag implementation. My idea was to extract the tag from a website, paste it there and see if it works in a clean environment, just the way it was on the previous website. Makes sense? Thanks again!

Comment: Yea suppose i understand what you mean. Do you try to add several items to the form at once or one by one?

Comment: Also, the thing with htmlentities($value) is that it strips all possible hurtful tags, So where it read script it changes the < and > to it's "text" value.

Comment: Just one by one, I would like to add a single tag, render it, and also parse it to provide some insights by analyzing it, so it should always be on a one by one basis. Regarding the htmlentities() it's there just for testing purposes, I reached that stage when you start trying everything out.

Comment: have you tried the same thing without htmlentities() and it still doesn't work?

Comment: can you print_r the post variables?

Comment: @JimSundqvist, Yup, it adds the iFrame to the DOM, but broken, as shown in my question, with the empty src= and that.

Comment: @Demodave, Hey thanks for writing, this is the result of print_r the  $_POST array: SubmitArray ( [tag] =>   [send] => Submit ), tag is empty since it printed the broken iFrame tag there.

Comment: Just so I understand, you put the whole iframe tag within the text area and submit it correct, because my  example renders correctly using your code. It's some picture of a dinoworld free stomper pass

Comment: Yup, that is correct. Whole iframe tag, and submit. That's crazy, could it be something related to my server configuration ?